# What should I do when reviewing an answer of a question that should be closed?

Tags: discussion, first-post-review

So today I was reviewing First Posts and I went across this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/19930264

IMO, the answer answers the question, but the question should be closed because it's asking us to recommend or find some off-site resources.

What should I do to those?

Comment: There are some other related Meta posts on whether it's wrong to answer low-quality questions in the first place, and on whether it's constructive to tell people not to answer.

Comment: I can't see the question because I have less than 10k rep on this site - was the answer link-only? (Link-only answers should be flagged as NAA or VLQ).

Answer (score 20):

My personal way is the following: Press *Link*, and flag the question for closure (or vote to close if you have enough rep), then leave the answer be (Press the *No action needed* button). If it's an audit, you will have seen that when you pressed link (rarely, such answers are flagged as spam and audits).

Since the problem is the question, not the answer, I think downvotes are appropriate only if the user is experienced enough to know we don't accept questions like this, which is never in first post review. You can downvote the question, though.

Comment: *"I think downvotes are appropriate only if the user is experienced enough to know we don't accept questions like this"* Isn't that voting based on the user, rather than the content?

Comment: That's true, but I make an exception for first answers on questions that will Roomba anyway. In that case, I choose not demotivating users over moderating content

Comment: And I can't disagree. Certainly not advocating downvoting the newbie's answer, more "Should we downvote the answer even from an experienced user?" I go with "no" except for a few obvious rep-you-know-whats that I know... (Which, yes, is voting on the user, or more accurately the combination of user and content. All rules have exceptions. :-) )

Comment: I would consider commenting on the answer something along the lines of "this question is [reason for closure], instead of answering you should flag it for closure"

Comment: @Draco18s but that is rather preachy and annoying. There's no rule against answering questions that aren't yet closed as far as I know. It would be equivalent to commenting "what have you tried?" under every how-to question ever asked ever (and that behavior has already been banned, so...)

Comment: Hence "consider." I think I've done it a grand total of four times ever. The two most recent were answers from 1 rep users who may not have known about the rules for closure.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if we compared names of those users, I think we could come to an agreement :) and it's not targetting the users, it's targetting the users _reputation_

Comment: Instead of vote for close you can consider to request to migrate to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com (if the question is detailed enough)